# How to extract saved password from Remmina?

Tags: password, remmina

I don't remember my password for one of my servers. I have a working connection saved and want to get the password from it.

From Remmina faq:

> Q: How are my passwords stored? Are they secure?
>   A: They are encrypted using 3DES with a 256bit randomly generated key. You should keep your key secure.

So where do I get the key and where would the passwords be stored?

EDIT:
Ok found that they are just in your users home folder under .remmina.
both the private key are in base64 and i can't seem to get the password right when decrypting......

Comment: The one-liner from https://askubuntu.com/a/1351463/545309 from @IcanDivideBy0  should be the the accepted answer (for Remmina versions younger than *7* years)

Answer (score 62):

I was able to use the Go solution by @michaelcochez to decrypt it with Python:

Python 3:

First install `pycryptodome` with pip:

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

```py
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

secret = base64.b64decode(b'<STRING FROM remmina.prefs>')
password = base64.b64decode(b'<STRING FROM XXXXXXX.remminaa>')

print(DES3.new(secret[:24], DES3.MODE_CBC, secret[24:]).decrypt(password).decode('utf-8'))
```

Original Python 2 Answer

```py
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

secret = base64.decodestring('<STRING FROM remmina.prefs>')
password = base64.decodestring('<STRING FROM XXXXXXX.remmina>')
    
print DES3.new(secret[:24], DES3.MODE_CBC, secret[24:]).decrypt(password)
```

Comment: For reasons that make me hate myself I needed a one-liner :/ : `python -c "import base64,sys;from Crypto.Cipher import DES3;pc=open('/home/admalledd/.remmina/remmina.pref').read();pci=pc.index('secret=');secret=pc[pci:pc.index('\n',pci)].split('=',1)[1];cc=open(sys.argv[1]).read();cci=cc.index('password');password=cc[cci:cc.index('\n',cci)].split('=',1)[1];secret,password=base64.decodestring(secret),base64.decodestring(password);  print DES3.new(secret[:24], DES3.MODE_CBC, secret[24:]).decrypt(password)" .remmina/1474332312568.remmina`. Left here for the next time I might need it.

Comment: Nice one.. Works just fine

Comment: The latest version of remmina has changed the location of these files. The pref file is now at: $HOME/.config/remmina/   and the connection file is listed at the bottom in remmina when you click on the connection (for example: ~/.local/share/remmina/4823893432523.remmina)

Comment: Thank you past self, slightly updated one-liner that takes two args for the files. `python -c "import base64,sys;from Crypto.Cipher import DES3;pc=open(sys.argv[1]).read();pci=pc.index('secret=');secret=pc[pci:pc.index('\n',pci)].split('=',1)[1];cc=open(sys.argv[2]).read();cci=cc.index('password');password=cc[cci:cc.index('\n',cci)].split('=',1)[1];secret,password=base64.decodestring(secret),base64.decodestring(password); print DES3.new(secret[:24], DES3.MODE_CBC, secret[24:]).decrypt(password)" /tmp/remmina/remmina.pref /tmp/remmina/00000000000.remmina`

Comment: @admalledd You really should post that as an answer!

Comment: In addition to what @Ring said, those files also seem to contain "password=." which makes Rinzwind's answer correct, too.

Comment: @admalledd I discovered that sometimes the string "password" substring occurs more than once.  if you match on "password=" that narrows it down, but still allowed for "gateway_password=" coming before the actual password to mess up the attempt.  I worked around this by editing the file and moving the actual password line up to near to top.

Answer (score 57):

They are stored in Gnome-Keyring.

Dash->type "keys"->Passwords&Keys.

In newer versions of seahorse (a.k.a. "Passwords and Keys") one has to select "View" -> "Show any" to see the keys.  Search for "remmina".

Comment: tried that already..... also i'm using lxde

Comment: This is true in some cases. Try this if the password listed in `~/.remmina/nnnnnnnnnnn.remmina` is just `.`.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Comment: FYI, the GUI to access the keyring can be launched by running `seahorse` from the terminal.

Comment: It works for me - thanks

Comment: It works for Linux Mint 19.3 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS based) and remmina 1.4.29. Just type seahorse in command-line, then pick "Default keyring", and you'll find what you want by name, it's self-explanatory.

Answer (score 19):

I found the key in a file called `~/.remmina/remmina.prefs` and the encrypted passwords are in `~/.remmina/nnnnnnnnnnn.remmina`.

I wrote a [code](http://play.golang.org/p/KXFlYCZNIC) (in Go) which can be used for decryption:

```go
//Decrypts obfuscated passwords by Remmina - The GTK+ Remote Desktop Client
//written by Michael Cochez
package main

import (
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/des"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

//set the variables here

var base64secret = "yoursecret"
var base64password = "theconnectionpassword"

//The secret is used for encrypting the passwords. This can typically be found from ~/.remmina/remmina.pref on the line containing 'secret='.
//"The encrypted password used for the connection. This can typically be found from /.remmina/dddddddddddd.remmina " on the line containing 'password='.
//Copy everything after the '=' sign. Also include final '=' signs if they happen to be there.

//returns a function which can be used for decrypting passwords
func makeRemminaDecrypter(base64secret string) func(string) string {
    //decode the secret
    secret, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(base64secret)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Base 64 decoding failed:", err)
    }
    if len(secret) != 32 {
        log.Fatal("the secret is not 32 bytes long")
    }
    //the key is the 24 first bits of the secret
    key := secret[:24]
    //3DES cipher
    block, err := des.NewTripleDESCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed creating the 3Des cipher block", err)
    }
    //the rest of the secret is the iv
    iv := secret[24:]
    decrypter := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)

    return func(encodedEncryptedPassword string) string {
        encryptedPassword, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encodedEncryptedPassword)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Base 64 decoding failed:", err)
        }
        //in place decryption
        decrypter.CryptBlocks(encryptedPassword, encryptedPassword)
        return string(encryptedPassword)
    }
}

func main() {

    if base64secret == "yoursecret" || base64password == "theconnectionpassword" {

        log.Fatal("both base64secret and base64password variables must be set")
    }

    decrypter := makeRemminaDecrypter(base64secret)

    fmt.Printf("Passwd : %v\n", decrypter(base64password))

}
```

The code can be run online, but then you are trusting golang.org.

Answer (score 18):

Remmina (1.3.3) store passwords thanks to `libsecret`, the `libsecret-tools` package can help you retrieve the stored password.

I was looking for the password of a Windows RDP connection with user password saved; I finnaly found the password with the command

```
secret-tool search key password
```

Comment: This should be accepted the answer. Thank you very very much!

Comment: Yes, most answers are totally obsolete and it took some time to find this.

Comment: The release notes state, that 1.2.0-rcgit.6 (2015-12-10) is the version Remmina moved to libsecret, so more than 7 years ago.  `--all` could be added to the command: `secret-tool search --all key password`

Answer (score 12):

I made a script that automatically decrypt your password files. The most recent version is at https://github.com/peppelinux/remmina_password_exposer.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
import base64
import os
import re

from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

# costanti :)
REMMINA_FOLDER = os.getenv('REMMINA_FOLDER', home+'/'+'.remmina/')
REMMINA_PREF   = 'remmina.pref'

REGEXP_ACCOUNTS = r'[0-9]{13}\.remmina(.swp)?'
REGEXP_PREF     = r'remmina.pref'

diz = {}

fs = open(REMMINA_FOLDER+REMMINA_PREF)
fso = fs.readlines()
fs.close()

for i in fso:
    if re.findall(r'secret=', i):
        r_secret = i[len(r'secret='):][:-1]
        print 'found secret', r_secret

for f in os.listdir(REMMINA_FOLDER):
    if re.findall(REGEXP_ACCOUNTS, f): 

        o = open( REMMINA_FOLDER+f, 'r')
        fo = o.readlines()
        o.close()

        for i in fo:
            if re.findall(r'password=', i):
                r_password = i[len(r'password='):][:-1]
            if re.findall(r'^name=', i):
                r_name = i.split('=')[1][:-1]
            if re.findall(r'username=', i):
                r_username = i.split('=')[1][:-1]
        #~ print fo
        #~ print 'found', f

        password = base64.decodestring(r_password)
        secret = base64.decodestring(r_secret)

        diz[r_name] = DES3.new(secret[:24], DES3.MODE_CBC, secret[24:]).decrypt(password)
        # print the username and password of the last decryption
        print r_name, r_username, diz[r_name]
```

Comment: `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pycrypto`
`python3 remmina_password_exposer.py`

Answer (score 2):

I created a perl script to decode remmina passwords. It extract your key and decode all your saved passwords (locally).

https://github.com/lepe/scripts/blob/master/decode_remmina.pl (check for updated version)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::CBC; #Crypt::DES_EDE3
use MIME::Base64;
use File::Slurp;

my $remmina_dir = $ENV{"HOME"} . "/.remmina";
my $remmina_cfg = $remmina_dir . "/remmina.pref";

my $content = read_file($remmina_cfg);
if($content) {
    my ($secret) = $content =~ /^secret=(.*)/m;
    if($secret) {
        my $secret_bin = decode_base64($secret);
        my ($key, $iv) = ( $secret_bin =~ /.{0,24}/gs );
        my @files = <$remmina_dir/*.remmina>;

        my $des = Crypt::CBC->new( 
                -cipher=>'DES_EDE3', 
                -key=>$key, 
                -iv=>$iv,
                -header=>'none', 
                -literal_key=>1,
                -padding=>'null'
        ); 
        if(@files > 0) {
            foreach my $file (@files) {
                my $config = read_file($file);
                my ($password) = $config =~ /^password=(.*)/m;
                my ($name) = $config =~ /^name=(.*)/m;
                my ($host) = $config =~ /^server=(.*)/m;
                my ($user) = $config =~ /^username=(.*)/m;
                my $pass_bin = decode_base64($password);
                my $pass_plain = $des->decrypt( $pass_bin );
                if($pass_plain) {
                    print "$name    $host   $user   $pass_plain\n";
                }
            }
        } else {
            print "Unable to find *.remmina files \n";
        }
    } else {
        print "No secret key found...\n";
    }
} else {
    print "Unable to read content from remmina.pref\n";
}
```

You will need to install these packages (for example, using `cpan <PACKAGE>`): `Crypt::CBC`, `Crypt::DES_EDE3`, `MIME::Base64`, `File::Slurp`

#### Sample output:

(Name, host, user, password: tab separated)

```
Server1 192.168.1.25    administrator   jM822Azss2fake
Server2 192.168.1.88:2899   admin   JaxHaxFakez90
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "seahorse" GUI for gnome-keyring to view & copy passwords from Remmina. Easy & Fast.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the reverse and encrypt passwords for Remmina using a Python script. In case anyone needs it here's the code:

```py
import base64    
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

REMMINAPREF_SECRET_B64=b'G5XKhImmX+3MaRAWU920B31AtQLDcWEq+Geq4L+7sES='

def encryptRemminaPass(plain):
    plain = plain.encode('utf-8')
    secret = base64.b64decode(REMMINAPREF_SECRET_B64)
    key = secret[:24]
    iv = secret[24:]
    plain = plain + b"\0" * (8 - len(plain) % 8)
    cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CBC, iv)
    result = cipher.encrypt(plain)
    result = base64.b64encode(result)
    result = result.decode('utf-8')
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

**BASH VERSION**

Get secret from remmina.pref, which is in ~/.config/remmina

```
s=`sed -n 's/^secret=//p' remmina.pref|base64 -d|hexdump -ve '/1 "%02x"'`
```

Decrypt:

```
echo CRYPTEDPW|openssl des3 -d -a -nopad -K ${s:0:48} -iv ${s:48}|tr -d "\0"
```

Encrypt (alternative to `remmina --encrypt-password`):

```
pw="PASSWORD"
pad=`printf "%*s" $[8-${#pw}%8] ""`
printf "$pw${pad// /\\0}"|openssl des3 -a -nopad -K ${s:0:48} -iv ${s:48}
```

Note, that the string padding during encrypting/decrypting is different between remmina and openssl. That's why `-nopad` option and the manual padding are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to go from key to password

key is in: ~/.config/remmina/remmina.pref
Password hash is in: ~/.local/share/remmina/*.remmina

To run, save as .py file replace 'key' and 'passw' fields and run python3 *.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import base64    
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

REMMINAPREF_SECRET_B64=b'KEY FROM REMMINA PREFS'

print ("Place Secret up and pasword below")

passw = "ENCRYPTED PASSSWORD"
passw = base64.b64decode(passw)
secret = base64.b64decode(REMMINAPREF_SECRET_B64)
key = secret[:24]
iv = secret[24:]
cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CBC, iv)
result = cipher.decrypt(passw)
result = result.decode('utf-8')
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

@IcanDivideBy0 solution worked for me on Xubuntu18.04 Remmina

```
sudo apt install -y libsecret-tools
secret-tool search key password
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1295021)