# Where does Remmina store the encrypted password?

Tags: encryption, remote-desktop, vnc, remmina

I have a Remmina connection with a saved password. I need that password for an other connection but I forgot it, so I would like to take it from the existing connection.

I'm well aware of: [How to extract saved password from Remmina?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290824/how-to-extract-saved-password-from-remmina?answertab=active#tab-top) however **all** the answers appear to be *outdated*.

My Remmina is version 1.4.2 and this is what I find when I try to search for the encrypted password in my configuration files:

```
$ grep -ir 'password' ./.local/share/remmina/*
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:password=.
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:ssh_tunnel_password=
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:gateway_password=
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:disablepasswordstoring=0
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:password=.
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:ssh_tunnel_password=
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:gateway_password=
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:disablepasswordstoring=0
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:password=
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:ssh_tunnel_password=
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:gateway_password=
./.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xxxx.remmina:disablepasswordstoring=0
./.local/share/remmina/group_vnc_yyyy.remmina:password=.
./.local/share/remmina/group_vnc_yyyy.remmina:disablepasswordstoring=0
./.local/share/remmina/group_vnc_yyyy.remmina:ssh_tunnel_password=
```

(Bolded lines are the ones for the connection with the saved password that works).

As you can see **there is no trace of an encrypted password. All answers to the question linked above assume I'd find `password=YW5zd2VycyBvdXRkYXRlZCE=` in one of these files!**

I use Kubuntu but Remmina is **not** using kwallet (I just disabled it and I can still use the `yyyy` connection which is the one with the password stored).

So where the heck does Remmina store said encrypted password? I already found the secret, so once I have the encrypted password it's easy to get the password back... but without finding the encrypted password it's impossible.

Comment: Okay, I just noted that I can copy&paste the remmina connection and the password gets copied. So if the purpose of recovery the password is to create new connections I can just use copy&paste... however I still would like to be able to retrieve the password. I have no idea why Remmina doesn't simply offer a button to display it in the GUI like any other program... the only reason I can think of is that Remmina was **Designed** so that person A configures the connections and gives them to person B while keeping the passwords secure but this cannot be the use case...

Comment: Good for you for finding all these files... all I find are my connections and the `password` config key is empty (even though there are passwords in each and every one of them). I mean, there is a away to retrieve the password, which is really not hard to do, providing that we know where to find it's location. So the whole thing is just to make things complicated more than anything else. (**EDIT:** I found the password in the GnuPG Keys app. You can actually retrieve it in clear from there.)

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 20.04, under Gnome, Remmina stores it's passwords in the GnuPG Keyring app.

[image]

From there you can retrieve them as clear text.

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu and, AFAIK, I have no keyring configured because I use KeePass. I just double checked and KWallet is disabled, KDE shouldn't have other systems to store passwords.

Comment: Well, sorry to hear that. I will update the answer to specify that this is for Gnome with Keyring enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Although you asked for stored encrypted password place of Remmina, but you want to get saved password, so I think this can help you.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
I found the solution for getting saved vpn password of Remmina from your mentioned post's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/1351463/125386). It worked, very simple.

```
$ sudo apt install libsecret-tools
$ secret-tool search key password
```

Password will be in the output with "secret" name.