# Where is stored the Certificate when the first Remmina connection was accomplished?

Tags: password, remote-desktop, certificates, remmina

For `Ubuntu Desktop` **22.04** and when `Remmina` (**1.4.25+dfsg**) as client does the first attempt of connection to a remote host (in this case other Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 too), once written the valid username and password, **only** for the first time appears a dialog window with the option to accept a `Certificate`, only when is accepted the connection can be established. For the coming connections that dialog window does not appear anymore and the username and password are not requested too, therefore the newer connections are accomplished directly.

**Question**

Where is stored that certificate?

**Reason**

For academic purposes, I want to delete that certificate *to simulate again the first connection* to see again the dialog window where the `Certificate` appears.

**Note**

I deleted the `Certificate` though the GUI according with

- [Where does Remmina store the encrypted password?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1264777/970554)

But when the next connection is tried, *it is accomplished directly*, therefore does not appear the dialog window as expected.

Furthermore according with [How to extract saved password from Remmina?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290824/how-to-extract-saved-password-from-remmina)
should exists the `~/.remmina` directory, but it does not exist.

How accomplish this goal? - See again the Dialog Window to accept the `Certificate` as the first time.

Answer (score -1):

File is:
**~/.config/freerdp/known_hosts2**